# Inequality. in Probability

Tags: probability, self-study, normal-distribution, inequality

let $ X \sim N(0,1)$
Prove that $P(X\geq c) \leq e^{-ct +{{t^2}\over {2}} }\\
c\geq0, t\in \Bbb{R} $

I have applied chebyscheffs inequality to come to this result:
 $P(X\geq c) \leq {{1} \over {c^2}} - \phi( -c) $
but i cannot bring the exponential term with t. 
Any kind of help shall be appreciated.

Comment: [Please tell us](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info) what have you tried yet and where are you stuck?

Comment: as i have mentioned in the question, i  applied chebyscheffs inequality and have got the following result $P(X\geq c) \leq {{1} \over {c^2}} - \phi( -c) $. but i haveno idea about how to bring about. the extra variable "t"

Comment: Hint: Since the inequality holds for _all_ real numbers $t$, it must be that it holds when we choose the value of $t$ such that $e^{-ct+\frac{t^2}{2}}$ has the minimum possible value. So, for a given positive real number $c$, what choice of $t$ minimizes $e^{-ct+\frac{t^2}{2}}$? Can you prove the result for this particular value of the RHS? If so, you have proved the result for all choices of $t$. Do you see why?

Comment: i did as you have asked, differentiated the RHS wrt to "t" to find that the min. value is attained at $t=c$ and the RHS value would be $e^{{-c^2 }\over{2}}$. still i cannot prove how $e^{{-c^2 }\over{2}} \geq {{1} \over {c^2}} - \phi( -c) $

Comment: Good! Further hint: the Chebyshev inequality is inadequate to prove the result. Use the Chernoff bound: For $c \geq 0$, $P\{X\geq c\}\leq e^{-c t}M_X(t), t\geq 0$. The proof uses the observation that $\mathbf 1_{x\colon x \geq c} \geq e^{x-c}$ for all $x$ and so $E[\mathbf 1_{x\colon x \geq c}] = P\{X\geq c]\leq E[e^{t(X-c)}]=e^{-ct}E[e^{tX}]$ is the MGF of $X$. Can you find the MGF of $X$? Can you prove the result now? If so, please write up your work and post it as an answer to your own question. Your earlier work will show that in fact you have proved that $P\{X\geq c\}\leq e^{-c^2/2}.$